# CFString (immutable) memory usage keeps on growing in IOS application

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm checking the memory usage of my IOS application using instruments, and found that CFString keeps on  being allocated and growing. I used StringWithFormat method, not something like [[NSString alloc] init] when creating NSString object in my code. How can I stop this? 
The following image is the screen capture of instrument's output.

Please tell me if necessary information for the question is missing.

[image: Instrument's screenshot]

Comment: You might try using ARC... In any case, you can browse the retain/release events for each listed object (and associated call stack for each eventq) in Instruments to help you track down the source of the problem. Finally, try the Analyze build style in Xcode to see if the static allocator points out any potential retain/release issues.

Comment: Please show the method where the string is being created.

Comment: @Ryo Is your issue resolved? What did you tried for that? Please let me know. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Pooja M. Bohora: Could you find solution?

Comment: @BaSha: I removed stringwithformat method of nsstring  as it creates autorelease strings

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora: Then what's alternative?

Comment: NSMutableString *result=@"";
    [result appendFormat:@""];

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora can you please help for this if you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good  practice to use custom autorelease pool blocks if you are  creating lot of temporary objects using convenience constructors.
Since objects created using convenience constructors are autoreleased they may not be released immediately. This is the reason for the spike in memory usage.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW2):

> Many programs create temporary objects that are autoreleased. These
>   objects add to the program’s memory footprint until the end of the
>   block. In many situations, allowing temporary objects to accumulate
>   until the end of the current event-loop iteration does not result in
>   excessive overhead; in some situations, however, you may create a
>   large number of temporary objects that add substantially to memory
>   footprint and that you want to dispose of more quickly. In these
>   latter cases, you can create your own autorelease pool block. At the
>   end of the block, the temporary objects are released, which typically
>   results in their deallocation thereby reducing the program’s memory
>   footprint.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/08/understanding-autoreleasing/

Answer (score 0):

In our case I discovered a continual leak of NSStrings (Many of which were of the class NSPlaceholderString which is a part of the class cluster) was due to NSZombieEnabled being on in the scheme.

Turning it off eliminated this source of memory leak.